# toFixed for integer?

Tags: javascript, datetime, int

Подскажите, я где-то видел аналог `toFixed` функции для форматирования целых чисел.
Функция ниже выводит дату так: `2.1.2017 3:1:27`, а я хочу, чтобы было так: `02.01.2017 03:01:27`.

Знаю, что для `float` чисел, можно использовать `toFixed` и там все окей. А как быть с интеджером?

Вот в C++ можно сделать так:

```
printf("%02i.%02i.%i %02i:%02i:%02i", day, month, year, hour, minute, second);
```

Моя функция вывода:

```
function utime2date(UNIX_timestamp){
    let a = new Date(UNIX_timestamp * 1000);
    let months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
    let year = a.getFullYear(); let month = a.getMonth(); let date = a.getDate(); let hour = a.getHours(); let min = a.getMinutes(); let sec = a.getSeconds();
    return date + '.' + month + '.' + year + ' ' + hour + ':' + min + ':' + sec ;
}
```

Подскажите аналог `toFixed` для `integer` чисел.

Comment: [.padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

Comment: Мне кажется, или `toFixed` работает не так, как `padStart`? Кстати, сейчас дату можно конвертировать в строку с форматом - `(new Date()).toLocaleString('ru')`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, принцип тот же: добавить символы, до нужной длины. Разница только в направлении, `.padStart` добавляет слева, а `.toFixed` справа, как `.padEnd`

Comment: @Grundy `.toFixed` еще добавляет точку, если ее не было и обрезает, если количество цифр после точки было больше, `padStart` - для string, `toFixed` для number. А так, если не учитывать всей этой разницы то да, это то же самое :)

Comment: Добавте везде условие такого типа: `if (day < 10) day = '0' + day;` или `day = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');` но последнее работает, только в новых браузерах.